# Proper way of loading javascript objects in memory?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I my webapp I use about 30 js files, each file containing 1 function. All these function are now selfinvoking and have references to each other.

The problem with this is that the order of scripts in the index.jsp matters. If a method is called on a function which has not been invoked yet we get a undefined error.

For a while we could overcome this by controlling the order of the `<script>` tags, but I would like to do this by using a loader script.

I have set up a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jorrebor/C2V2u/5/) to show my concept. My biggest concern is that I have to declare my objects globally, in order to have them be accessible in the `jquery(document).ready()` function.

Is this an OK pattern? Any hints highly appreciated!

Comment: Here's a tip that could help: In the IDE, have your 30 js. But when you compile the application, execute a script that combines all the js files together, remove empty space and comments. This will also make it a lot faster to download.

Comment: yeps, i'm using the YUI compressor for that. My question is more about code structure in order for it to be maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or similar loader, which would handle script dependencies for you.

You would need to modify each of JS file to make it a module in a similar fashion to this example:

```
// File: module3.js
define(["module1", "module2"], function(m1, m2) {
    // Here, module1 and module2 are guaranteed to be loaded.
});
```

Then, you would make one "main" script (I usually call it `main.js`) and require several modules:

```
require(["module3"], function (m3) {
  // Here module3 is loaded, as well as module1 and module2 
  // - because module3 depends on them.
});
```

And put this in your HTML:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

Comment: I went for a custom solution, but it basically does this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build your server-side architecture to serve proper js files (and other static files) per page. Create 1 minified js file for page and initialize objects scope in html files.